# PHP won't update JSON file

Tags: php, file-get-contents, json

This is what my JSON file currently looks like:

```
{"coins":"0","uses":"0"}
```

I'm trying to update it's values by using the following PHP:

```
$jsonString = file_get_contents('/path/money_maker.json');
$data = json_decode($jsonString);
$data["coins"] = $data["coins"] + $coins;
$data["uses"] = $data["uses"] + 1;
$newJsonString = json_encode($data);
file_put_contents('/path/money_maker.json', $newJsonString);
```

However, it's not working. How come? I've tried doing some research, but nothing has helped me thus far.

Comment: "Not working" is a very poor problem description, so I can only guess - it probably should be `json_decode($jsonString, true);` if you want to use it as an array. If you don't pass the second argument, you get an object back, so you would have to access the properties with `$data->coins;`.

Comment: `json_decode` returns an object, but you're treating it like an array. Use `json_decode(.., true)` if you want an array.

Answer (score 0):

the content of the file is json object.you cant use it like array.try this

```
$jsonString = file_get_contents('money-maker.json');
$data = json_decode($jsonString);
$data->coins = $data->coins + $coins;
$data->uses = $data->uses + 1;
$newJsonString = json_encode($data);
file_put_contents('money-maker.json', $newJsonString);
```

or you can convert it first then use it.

Answer (score 0):

The answer by sgt is correct, but you can also have json_decode create arrays instead of objects as seen in the PHP manual (https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) by using the assoc parameter: `$data = json_decode($jsonString, true);`